# Wagtail: How to set InlinePanel Child Label based on model fields?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

How can I set the label on the InlinePanel child ("Field 1") to a value based on fields of a model being added?
[image: InlinePanel Form fields - Field N]

My models:

```py
class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    label = models.CharField(
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_("label"),
        max_length=255,
        help_text=_("The label of the form field"),
    )
    field_type = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="field type",
        max_length=16,
        choices=(("section", "Section"),) + FORM_FIELD_CHOICES,
    )
    page = ParentalKey(
        'ContactPageBase',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='form_fields',
    )
```

And contact form page:

```py
class ContactPageBase(WagtailCaptchaEmailForm, BasePage):
    ...
    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('contact_intro'),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', heading=_('Form fields'), label=_("Field")),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text')
    ]
```

I understand the label can be edited like above but that is for the whole set of children in the InlinePanel but I would like to show something like "{FormField.field_type} - {FormField.label}" in the label so it's clear in the overview on the right. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Like the parameter [`label_format`](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/streamfield/blocks.html#wagtail.blocks.StructBlock)?

Comment: @padaleiana That attribute is not present for `InlinePanel`.

Answer (score 0):

To set the label on the InlinePanel child dynamically based on the fields of the model being added, you can override the **str** method in your FormField model.

```
class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.get_field_type_display()} - {self.label}"

class ContactPageBase(Page):
    ...

    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('contact_intro'),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label=_("Field")),
        FieldPanel('thank_you_text')
    ]
```

Comment: This does not solve it. Implemented exactly what you said but it's never called in the admin UI for panels.